# Preparedstatement java

Tags: java

I want to look for something that matches a enum: Divisions:U6,U7,U8...
It works when i do this.

```
public ArrayList<Training> zoekTrainingen(Ploegen p) throws
        ApplicationException {

    ArrayList<Training> tr = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection(driver,
            dburl, login, paswoord);
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select * from trainingen");) {
        stmt.execute();
        ResultSet r = stmt.getResultSet();

        while (r.next()) {
        ---

        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        throw new ApplicationException("");
    }
    finally {
        return tr;
    }
}

    }
```

but when I do this:

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select * from trainingen where Divsion = ?");) {
            stmt.setString(1, p.getDivision());
```

I get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is attempting to set a `String` parameter using an `Enum`.  It should get the `String` value of the Enum and pass to the `setString` method.

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select * from trainingen where Divsion = ?");) {
            stmt.setString(1, p.getDivision().toString());
```

Comment: I defined it in my enum it's retrieving the string and your solution doens't work too. But thanks though.

Comment: Make sure `getDivision` is not returning null.  You can also run a simple test by adding a hard coded value in the setString method. `setString(1,"something")`

Comment: Thanks, the hard coded value works but there must be something wrong with the enum then. With tis: stmt.setString(1, p.getDivision());   it goes directly to the catch

Comment: p.getDivision() returns null

Comment: So somewhere in your code before calling this method, the object supplied to the `Ploegen p` argument of the `zoekTrainingen` method needs to have the Division set.  Once set, I still believe you may need to call the `toString` method on the Enum.